# Is it possible to trade from an emulator into a nintendo device?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

want to know, if it is worth shiny hunting on pokemon crystal, so if I get a shiny, I can trade it to not an emulator, and not be afraid of losing a shiny ,if my phone loses all of it's info.

Comment: If you're using an emulator, why not back up your save files on PC, online drives, etc.? Trading between emulator and a Nintendo device seems to be impossible...The only thing I could find is transferring saves from emulator to a Nintendo device and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, yeah, there is a way. But it requires third-party hardware.

For this to work, you will need:

- 2 Gameboy Colors/Advances
- A link cable
- A GBC Flash Cart of your choosing (preferably one compatible with the emulator you're using).
- A compatible SD card

**Step 1: Transfer files to SD card**

I recommend following a video tutorial for transferring emulator files onto your Flash Cart because this part is a little bit complicated and may need a better tutorial than plain text.

**Step 2: Start up the games**

Once you have successfully transferred your emulator files onto your Flash Cart, put both your official copy of the Gen 2 games and your Flash Cart into compatible Gameboy systems. These devices must be able to connect via link cable.

**Step 3: Initiate trade**

After both games have started up, connect the link cable to each device, head to a Pokémon center, and set up a trade room. Select the Pokémon you want to trade (in this case your shiny along with a throwaway, likely a Ladyba or Sentret) and accept the trade.

If done correctly, your shiny has been successfully transferred to an official cartridge. Your shiny now has a new home with legitimate non-emulator Pokémon. Nobody will know the difference ;)